# Iframe wrapper when using Azure trafficmanager

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I have a website hosted in Azure and I have traffic manager in front. I also have a CNAME created for the traffic manager.

When I hit the trafficmanager url, I get the the expect HTML response back. But when I hit the CNAME url, I get html back that is basically an iframe with the src pointing to the trafficmanager url. I don't understand where is this coming from. This is what the response looks like:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Site Name</title>
      <meta name="keywords" content=""
   </head>
   <frameset rows="100%", *" border="0" frameborder="0">
   <frame src="mysite.trafficmanager.net" name="mysite">
   </frameset>
</html>
```

Has anyone run into this before? Is this even expected?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic Manager only does DNS resolution, so any HTTP traffic being sent to or from the client has nothing to do with traffic manager.  You can use nslookup to make sure that the IP address that your trafficmanager URL reuturns is the same IP address that your CNAME returns.  If they are not the same, then you have something wrong in your DNS configuration.  If they are the same, then your site is handling the two host headers differently and you need to look at your website.